# Something in Spring like 'init-method' but called after dependencies are injected?

Tags: spring

This is crazy... been using Spring for a while but can't find something like the "init-method" that gets invoked AFTER all the dependencies have been injected.

I saw the BeanPostProcessor thingie but I am looking for something lightweight and non-intrusive that doesn't couple my beans to Spring.  Like the init-method!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With Spring 2.5 and above, if an object requires invocation of a callback method upon initialization, that method can be annotated with the `@PostConstruct` annotation.

For example:

```
public class MyClass{

   @PostConstruct
   public void myMethod() {
     ...
   }
   ...
}
```

This is less intrusive than the `BeanPostProcessor` approach.

Comment: But then I have to include Spring on the build path when building my pojos... there's no XML-only way?

Comment: Nevermind, I see that @PostConstruct is in the javax.annotation package.  Thanks!

Comment: See some caveats in the comments here if you have circular dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406631/32453

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, [the init-method **is** called after all dependencies are injected](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle). Try it out:

```
public class TestSpringBean
{
    public TestSpringBean(){
        System.out.println( "Called constructor" );
    }

    public void setAnimal( String animal ){
        System.out.println( "Animal set to '" + animal + "'");
    }

    public void setAnother( TestSpringBean another ){
        System.out.println( "Another set to " + another );
    }

    public void init(){
        System.out.println( "Called init()" );
    }
}

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="myBean" class="TestSpringBean" init-method="init">
        <property name="animal" value="hedgehog" />
        <property name="another" ref="depBean" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="depBean" class="TestSpringBean"/>

</beans>
```

This yields:

```
Called constructor
Called constructor
Animal set to 'hedgehog'
Another set to com.et.idp.wf.integration.TestSpringBean@7d95d4fe
Called init()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) interface and override the `afterPropertiesSet` method.

Comment: But then I have to include Spring on the build path when building my pojos... there's no XML-only way?