# SessionScoped Managed bean injection is not working

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, cdi, jsf-2.2, managed-bean

This is my SessionScoped managed bean :

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("clientSessionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ClientSessionManagedBean implements Serializable {
...
}
```

This is my requestscoped managed bean

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped; 
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;   

@Named("myBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MyManagedBean {

 @Inject
 private ClientSessionManagedBean clientSessionBean;
 ..
 }
```

The value `clientSessionBean` giving me `null` .

How can I inject a sessionScoped bean in a requestscoped managed bean ?

Is there any problem with the package ?

Comment: Show us how you are using `MyManagedBean` bean object?

Comment: In jsf by using jstl tags

Comment: `MyManagedBean` is a controller? or it is used from a controller?

Comment: No I used only in my jsf file , it is not used in any controller

Comment: Can you add post construct and pre-destroy method i you session scoped bean and try to check when pre-destroy method is called.

Comment: And can you check your code without implementing Serializable interface in session scoped bean.

Comment: Do you use the sessionScoped bean somewhere in your page? Check with a @PostConstruct if it is created at all

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried the most basic - is the `beans.xml` in the right place?

Comment: Are you trying to access the injected bean in the constructor of the target?

Comment: Yes.. Exactly. I was trying to access the injected bean in constructor.

Comment: Instead of injecting in the constructor use the @PostConstruct method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injected resources are available only *after* the constructor has run, i.e. during `@PostConstruct` and beyond. From the spec docs for JSR-250:

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed ***after*** dependency injection is done to perform any initialization

As you should be able to infer from the excerpt above, the sequence of events in the lifecycle of a bean is:

1. Initialization i.e. calling the constructor (the actual mechanism is more complex, but it boils down to this)
2. Performing injections
3. Call lifecycle callback, i.e. `@PostConstruct`. It's at this point, that you're allowed to make use of anything that was created in #2

Related

- [Why use @PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct)
- [Initialization of List in a JSF Managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773350/initialization-of-list-in-a-jsf-managed-bean/15774143#15774143) (point #3)