# use JSF to display a list

Tags: eclipse, xhtml, jsf-2.2

I tried to display the list of products using JSF but nothing is displayed the list is not empty is there is no error.
here is the code of the xhtml page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
<h:dataTable var="p" value="#{produitController.findAll()}">
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">id</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="${p.id}"></h:outputText>
</h:column>
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">name</f:facet> 
<h:outputText value="${p.name}"></h:outputText>
</h:column></h:dataTable>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And this is class code:

```
  @ManagedBean(name="produitController")
  @SessionScoped
  public class produitController
  {private Produit produit=new Produit();
   public String page()
   {
    return "page";
    }
    public Produit getProduit() {
      return produit;
     }
     public void setProduit(Produit produit) {
      this.produit = produit;
    }

    public List<Produit>  findAll(){
    List<Produit> listProduit=new ArrayList<Produit>();
    listProduit.add(new Produit("1", "produit 1",1500, new Date())); 
    return listProduit;

    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check  If JSF Works At All

Comment: How should I know if it's working?

Comment: By implementing a 'helloworld'? Vua a basic tutorial from http://jsf.zeef.com

Comment: i have display a "hello work" in a  inputText and it worked (<h:outputLabel value="Hello word"></h:outputLabel>)

Comment: You don't eve see an empty datatable? No headers? What does a 'view-source' do on the client side of this page?

Comment: can you explain to me more? or tell me what I need to change...

Comment: run your app in jsf development mode and debug...

Comment: At first glance, the way you're initializing the list looks suspect. [Do it in a PostConstruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773350/initialization-of-list-in-a-jsf-managed-bean/15774143#15774143) method and see what happens