# Why is there no @PreLoad entity listener?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, entitylisteners

here's the JPA2 entity listener annotations:

```
@PrePersist
@PreRemove
@PostPersist
@PostRemove
@PreUpdate
@PostUpdate
@PostLoad
```

However there is no @PreLoad annotation? How can that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would apply the same knowledge as with [JSF - what is the difference between @PostConstruct and direct method call from constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542003/jsf-what-is-the-difference-between-postconstruct-and-direct-method-call-from). `@PostLoad` is executed after the constructor and has all `JPA` related dependencies ready and the object of this class is actually `@Entity` and not a simple `Java` object. So non-existent `@PreLoad` would actually be constructor, but the `@Entity` is not an `@Entity` yet before `@PostLoad`.