# jsf cant get managedbean from session scope to another managedbean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to get a session scope managedbean in this way:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginBean implements Serializable{
......
}

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MenuBean implements Serializable{
@ManagedProperty(value="#{loginBean}")
private LoginBean login;      
public void setLogin(LoginBean login) {
this.login = login;
}

public LoginBean getLogin() {
return login;
}

...
}
```

But MenuBean loginBean is always null, what can I be doing wrong? can you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: First make sure you're importing your scoping annotations from the `javax.faces.*` package. Then also confirm `LoginBean` is actually being instantiated (i.e. no initialization-related exceptions in the logs etc)

Comment: Hello, yes my import look like this: import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage; import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty; import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped; import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext; import javax.faces.context.FacesContext; 

also try to get the bean in session like this:

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    LoginBean login= (LoginBean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{loginBean}", LoginBean.class);

if I do it this way I can get the bean with ManagedProperty I cant Thx 4 ur help

Comment: At what point are you trying to access `loginBean` and you're getting null? Not the constructor yeah?

Comment: im trying to get loginBean from the constructor of MenuBean, is this a bad way to do it?

Comment: Yes actually. Injected properties are not available as at then. I'll explain in an answer

Comment: Ok, i supposed that i can do it using @PostConstruct rigth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection of resources happens immediately *after* successful construction and as a result, you're not going to be able to use injected fields before or during construction of the bean. Hence, the need for [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmgkd.html). Injected properties are available for use in the `@PostConstruct` method (which executes immediately after construction, the *Post* in `@PostConstruct`)

**Related**

- [Why use @PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct)
- [JSF - what is the difference between @PostConstruct and direct method call from constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542003/jsf-what-is-the-difference-between-postconstruct-and-direct-method-call-from)
- [Initialization of List in a JSF Managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773350/initialization-of-list-in-a-jsf-managed-bean/15774143#15774143) (item #3)

Comment: Many many thanks Kolossus! u save my day!!