# Spring: circular dependencies, @PostConstruct and order imposed by @DependsOn

Tags: java, spring

I was expecting Spring to take `@DependsOn` into account when calling `@PostConstruct` methods, but seems like it's not the case in presence of circular (auto-wired) dependencies.

Consider two beans (code below), `BeanB @DependsOn BeanA`. When field `BeanA#b` has it's `@Autowired` commented out, post-construct methods are called in expected order: first A, then B. But with `@Autowired` in effect for A, I have B's `post` called first, *then* A's `post`.

I understand this is a bad design (actually, it's minimal demo of very big `@Autowired` ... code-base), but I was expecting Spring to finish injection of `@Autowired` fields and *then* starting to call lifecycle callbacks, honoring `@DependsOn`, but Spring seems to ignore `@DependsOn` order when there are circular deps.

Spring version is 4.1.5.

So, is this **my misunderstanding** or **undocumented behavior** or can it be considered **a Spring bug** (or, perhaps, feature request)?

```
@Component
class BeanA {

    // @Autowired
    private BeanB b;

    void f() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void post() {
        System.out.println("A done");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bean{" +
                "b=" + (b == null ? null : b.getClass()) +
                '}';
    }
}
// ---------------------
@Component
@DependsOn("beanA")
class BeanB {

    @Autowired
    private BeanA a;

    void f() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void post() {
        System.out.println("B done");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BeanB{" +
                "a=" + (a == null ? null : a.getClass()) +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In the chapter about [*Initialization callbacks*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean), the Spring documentation states

> [`@PostConstruct` and other methods] allows a bean to perform
>   initialization work after all necessary properties on the bean have
>   been set by the container.

With your commented code, the following happens: `beanA` is instantiated and saved. The container sees that all necessary properties have been set and it invokes the init (`@PostConstruct`) method. Then it goes to `beanB` which it initializes, saves, sees an `@Autowired`, retrieves the saved `beanA`, injects it, the runs `beanB`'s `@PostConstruct` since all its properties have been set.

In your uncommented code, you have a case of circular dependencies. `beanA` gets instantiated first and is saved. The container notices it has an injection target of type `BeanB`. To perform this injection, it needs the `beanB` bean. It therefore instantiates the bean, saves it, sees that it has a dependency on a `beanA` as an injection target. It retrieves the `beanA` (which was saved earlier), injects it, then `beanB`'s properties are all set and its `@PostConstruct` method is invoked. Finally, this initialized `beanB` bean is injected into `beanA`, whose `@PostConstruct` method is then invoked since all its properties have been set.

This second has case `beanB` being constructed while `beanA` is being constructed. This is how Spring solves the following

```
class A {
    private B b;
}

class B {
    private A a;
}
```

An instance of each has to be created before either can be injected into the other.

---

If you get rid of the `@DependsOn`, you'll get the same behavior (but just because of the default ordering of classpath scanning, which seems to be alphabetical). If you renamed `BeanA` to `BeanZ`, for example, the `beanB` will be instantiated first, then `beanZ` would get instantiated, initialized, and returned to be injected into `beanB`.

`@DependsOn` is really only necessary if you have side effects that you'd like to happen before a bean is initialized.

Comment: Exactly -- for B there's side-effect dependency (in full version, not in my sample code): on A's lifecycle callback to be completed before B's own `@PostConstruct` is called. And I was going to ensure this using `@DependsOn`, but -- alas!

Comment: In real code issue is resolved by calling needed logic from out-side code, once Spring context is instantiated, instead of relying on `B#postConstruct()`.

Comment: I've added emphasis to my post to make actual question more explicit.

Comment: @VictorSorokin I think it's a misinterpretation on your part. [`@DependsOn`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) guarantees creation order, and, truly, in both your examples (if you add a SOP to a parameterless constructor), `beanA` is _created_ first. Initialization is another matter. Spring caches beans it creates so that it can resolve circular dependencies like the one in your snippet (or my answer). Turn on DEBUG logs to see it in action.

Comment: @VictorSorokin But I'd like to know what behavior you'd want in the uncommented case. Would you expect `beanA` to be created, then `beanB` be created (but not initialized), injected into `beanA`, then the container go back to finalizing initialization of `beanB`? Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I've been expecting Spring to instantiate all bean objects, inject `@Autowired` fields, then start calling lifecycle callbacks in some order which does not violate existing `@DependsOn`.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Sotirios' answer, and with some investigation:

```
class A {
    private B b;
}

class B {
    private A a;
}
```

What spring will do is instantiate an `a` and `b`,

Then it does "setup phase" for `a`.  It sets `a.b=b;`   Then it will call `@PostConstruct` method on `a`.

Then it does "setup" for b.  It sets `b.a=a;` and then calls `@PostConstruct` method on b.

So if you look carefully, at `a`'s `@PostConstruct` time, `b` hasn't been..fully set up yet.  Like...`@AutoWired`'s haven't even been assigned yet.

`b.a` is null during `a`'s `@PostConstruct`.

Apparently this is "the spring way"?

So if `a`'s `@PostConstruct` calls some method on b `b.tell_me_about_a`, b's circular `a` will not be assigned yet, so the end result (if tell_me_about_a calls a method of `a`) is a callstack that's like

```
NullPointerException # calling some A method
    someLineOfB
    somePostConstructMethodOfA
```

However, during `b`'s `@PostConstruct` `b.a` will have the instance already fully initiated, and is *not* lacking its `@AutoWired`'s, so `b.a.b` will not be a NullPointerException.  Confusing...

`@DependsOn` can change some ordering.  But it seems that it's in the opposite order to what you'd [expect](https://gist.github.com/rdp/6cd55fe35a9f7d1f260995944bd9e0e5).
I think you are right when it is circular you can't depend on @DependsOn [?] Because it works as expected (runs PostConstruct's in the expected order if there isn't. To me this feels like a bug.

You can see this behavior in action by adding spring [logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e826), then you'll see messages like `DEBUG main support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:247 - Returning eagerly cached instance of singleton bean 'beanA' that is not fully initialized yet - a consequence of a circular reference` [demo](https://gist.github.com/rdp/6cd55fe35a9f7d1f260995944bd9e0e5)

Ways you can fix it:

Be careful using methods of injected dependencies during PostConstruct.  Or call none.

Using spring-wired constructor parameters instead of `@AutoWired/@Inject` at all.  Spring disallows circular in that case.  Which may be what you want anyway...

Use @DependsOn in reverse order? what?...