# Spring Autowired Swing objects NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, swing

I am using spring for dependency injection, so I have a class which uses swing for user interface, however when I want to use `@Autowired` for any swing objects I get NullPointerException.

Here is the class:

```
@Component
public class PanelImpl implements Panel {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("getJPanel")
    private JPanel panel;

    //@Autowired
    private JButton getInfoBtn = new JButton();

    public PanelImpl() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setPanel();
    }

    private void setPanel() {
        getInfoBtn.setText("Get Info");
        panel.add(getInfoBtn);
    }

    @Override
    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }
}
```

And here is the Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ooc")
@PropertySource("app.properties")
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Panel getPanel() {
        Panel PanelImpl = new PanelImpl();
        return PanelImpl;
    }


    @Bean
    public JPanel getJPanel(){
        return new JPanel();
    }

}
```

So any suggestions how I can use spring for injecting swing objects?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@PostConstruct` solved my problem. It will ensure all the dependencies are injected before executing the method.

```
@Component
public class PanelImpl implements Panel {

    @Autowired
    private JPanel panel;

    @Autowired
    private JButton getInfoBtn;

    @PostConstruct
    private void setPanel() {
        getInfoBtn.setText("Get Info");
        panel.add(getInfoBtn);
    }

    @Override
    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take care to not overuse `@Autowired` -- it easily leads to unmaintainable mess. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260676. Even Spring reference warns against `@Autowired`: see table 5.2 at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-autowire

Comment: @VictorSorokin , thanks for your comment. So what's your suggestion for not overusing `@Autowired` ?

Comment: Use explicit dependencies -- via constructor or via setters. It takes more keystrokes but you have much more clear codebase and you unit test w/o Spring (since it's possible to pass dependencies from test-case code to your objects).