# Spring not inject circular dependency in @PostConstruct time

Tags: java, spring

I use spring version 4.1.6.RELEASE and I have found strange thing. After

> @PostConstruct private void initialize( carServiceImpl..)

method is called its have dependency an other Service which have Autowired DAOs and Services. I have found that in PostConstruct spring inject only first properties -on top of the newRequestService. If I move down for example carsRegionChangesService below newRequestService the last one carsRegionChangesService=null and newRequestService=null.

```
@Service
public class CarsServiceImpl implements CarsService {    

@Autowired
    private CarsDAO carsDAO;
    @Autowired
    private CarsDao carsDao;
    @Autowired
    private CarsTypesService carsTypesService;
    @Autowired
    private RegionsService regionsService;
    @Autowired
    private RegionsDependenceService regionsDependenceService;
    @Autowired
    private CarsRegionChangesService carsRegionChangesService;
    @Autowired
    private NewRequestService newRequestService; //this = null
}
```

I have NullPointerException from not injected properties:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.stil.db.service.CarsServiceImpl.getCarsFromRegion(CarsServiceImpl.java:238)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.getCarsFromRegion(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.stil.db.service.NewRequestServiceImpl.getCarsListForUpdate(NewRequestServiceImpl.java:809)
>     at
>   com.stil.db.service.NewRequestServiceImpl.getCarsListForUpdate(NewRequestServiceImpl.java:750)
>     at
>   com.stil.db.service.NewRequestServiceImpl.greenRequest(NewRequestServiceImpl.java:312)
>     at
>   com.stil.db.service.NewRequestServiceImpl.initialize(NewRequestServiceImpl.java:149)

any idea? In runtime after initialize with PostConstruct this problem not exist all properties are injected.

Comment: If it is true what you show here then you have a circulair dependency in your beans. (`CarServiceImpl` depends on `NewRequestServiceImpl`) and due to that the dependency is `null` (at that moment). Circular references are a bad thing and basically a sign that there is something wrong in your application.

Comment: Yes it is true I have circular dependency. I was thinking that spring deal with this: from the Spring Reference: You can generally trust Spring to do the right thing. It detects configuration problems, such as references to non-existent beans and circular dependencies, at container load-time. Spring sets properties and resolves dependencies as late as possible, when the bean is actually created.

Comment: After I remove dependency of NewRequestService in CarService problem disapear. Thanks @M.Deinum

Comment: But why spring not deal with the circular dependency in the @PostConstruct time ?

Comment: My IDE not show me warnings for the circular dependency. It was a stupid mistake after remove circular dependency and moving dependent code to other service it looks much better now. How can I easy detect circular dependency ?

Comment: How could it? Bean A needs Bean B? And before bean B is ready the post construct needs to be invoked, however at that time it isn't injected because it isn't ready yet...

Comment: Maybe spring documentation is not clear about circular dependency in  @PostConstruct time

Comment: imho it is clear documentation can never cover all the corner cases especially not in this case. Basically you shouldn't have circulair dependencies as they are more trouble then they are worth. They will bite you at some point.

Comment: @M.Deinum maybe little warning can be added about this issue in spring documentation :) I agree that I shouldn`t have it and just to share how can detect it. If you use intellij its have on the main menu Analyze -> Analyze Cyclic Dependencies

Comment: Due to the fact your stacktrace shows several different classes, you may have fallen victim to "Spring passes half instantiated objects when there are circular dependencies" https://stackoverflow.com/a/64649202/32453