# Spring autowiring order and @PostConstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have a question about auto-wiring order and `@PostConstruct` logic in Spring. For example following demo code I have a main Spring Boot class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo1Application {

    @Autowired
    BeanB beanb;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and 2 `@Service` Definitions:

```
@Service
public class BeanB {

    @Autowired
    private BeanA beana ;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("beanb is called");
    }

    public void printMe(){
        System.out.println("print me is called in Bean B");
    }
}

@Service
public class BeanA {

    @Autowired
    private BeanB b;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("bean a is called");
        b.printMe();
    }
}
```

and I have the following output:

> bean a is called
>
> print me is called in Bean B
>
> beanb is called

My question is how autowiring takes place step by step like a scenario above?
And how `printMe()` method of `beanb` is called without calling its `@PostConstruct` first?

Answer (score 26):

Below should be possible sequence

1. `beanb` starts to get autowired
2. During class initialization of `Beanb`, beana starts to get autowired
3. Once beana gets created the `@PostConstruct` i.e. `init()` of beana gets called
4. Inside `init()`, `System.out.println("bean a is called");` gets called
5. Then `b.printMe();` gets called causing `System.out.println("print me is called in Bean B");` to execute
6. Having the `beana` completed the `@PostConstruct` i.e. `init()` of `beanb` gets called
7. Then `System.out.println("beanb is called");` gets called

Ideally the same can be better observed by a debugger in eclipse.

The [Spring reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-dependency-resolution) explains how circular dependencies are resolved. The beans are instantiated first, then injected into each other.

Comment: [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-dependency-resolution) to circular dependency resolution.

Comment: Be careful with PostConstruct that "call through" to circular dependencies, they can still be null: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64649202/32453

Answer (score 6):

Your Answer is Correct as you shown in Your question.

Now Getting the concept of Notation `@Autowired`. All `@Autowired` Objects are initialized and loaded in memory just after class Loading is done.

Now here is your `SpringBootApplication`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo1Application {
    @Autowired
    BeanB beanb;   // You are trying to autowire a Bean class Named BeanB.
```

Here at above Console Application that you have write try to autowire and inject a object of type `BeanB`.

Now here is your definition of `BeanB`

```
@Service
public class BeanB {

    @Autowired
    private BeanA beana ;
```

In `BeanB` class you are trying to inject the Object of Class `BeanA` which is also defined in your console Project.

So, In Your `Demo1Application` to inject a Object of Class `BeanB` there must need to inject a Object of class `BeanA`.
Now `BeanA` Class Object is Created First.

Now if you see the definition of Your Class `BeanA`

```
 @Service
public class BeanA {

    @Autowired
    private BeanB b;

    @PostConstruct   // after Creating bean init() will be execute.
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("bean a is called");
        b.printMe();
    }
}
```

So, After injecting the Object `BeanA` method bind with  `@PostContruct` annotation is going to execute.

So, execution flow will be..

```
System.out.println("bean a is called");
System.out.println("print me is called in Bean B");
System.out.println("beanb is called");
```

Answer (score 0):

It will show class not found exception as class A depends on class B. and class B depends on class A.