# Should I never use @PostConstruct in Spring Boot when I have All Args Constructor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constructor-injection, postconstruct

In out project we don't use setter or filed injection, we use only constructor injection, and I know that both options 1. and 2. may work.

- **Is it unsafe** to work with beans in constructor in that case?

Or spring boot 2+ makes something, and I should better use option 1. instead of 2. I can't imagine case when option 1 will go wrong

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("config")
public class ServiceConfigProperties  {
    // .... some code
}
```

1. Can be unsafe? - but it looks better

```
@Component
public class Service {
    private boolean skipCheck;

    public Service(ServiceConfigProperties configProps) {
        this.skipCheck = configProps.isSkipCheck();
    }
}
```

2. Can't be unsafe?

```
@Component
public class Service {
    private boolean skipCheck;
    private ServiceConfigProperties configProps;

    public Service(ServiceConfigProperties configProps) {
        this.configProps= configProps;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initConfig() {
        this.skipCheck= configProps.isSkipCheck();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [a couple of caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068303/spring-autowiring-order-and-postconstruct), interacting with constructor-injected beans inside the constructor is completely safe.