# Why @PostConstruct causes NullPointerException?

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning Spring Framework, while watching Evgeniy Borisov's [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGfeSo52_8A&t=1934s) I came across this code:

Suppose we have two beans with circular dependency:

Second bean:

```
@Service
public class Two {

    @Autowired
    private One one;


    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    private String word;


    @PostConstruct
    public void doSmth(){
        init();
        System.out.println("SECOND BEAN TEXT :"+one.getWord());
    }

        public void init(){
            word = "Second word";
    }
}
```

First bean:

```
@Service
public class One {
    @Autowired
    private Two two;

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    private String word;

    @PostConstruct
    public void doSmth(){
        init();
        System.out.println("FIRST BEAN TEXT :"+two.getWord());
    }

    public void init(){
        word = "First bean";
    }
}
```

And start class:

```
public class StartTests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext configApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("test");
    }
}
```

If we execute StartTests class, we'll get this in output :

> SECOND BEAN TEXT :null
>
> FIRST BEAN TEXT :Second word

Yes, I understand that @PostConstructor executes before all proxies are involved, but I can't understand why First Bean works properly while Second Bean doesn't

Comment: printing out NULL is not the same as a NullPointerException

Comment: As you stated, there is a circulair reference. Hence one bean needs to be constructed and initialized BEFORE it can be injected into the other instance. Hence there will always be one that doesn't have the dependency injected before the `@PostConstruct` is executed.

Comment: That's not the case - there's no Nullpointerexception so both dependencies have been injected before PostConstruct, as they should be

Comment: Thank you! But in the lecture ( at 16 min you can look at code ) occurs Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Can somebody explain me, why in lecture with the same code occurs null pointer exception ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just about execution order.  **One** of them has to run first after all!

1. Spring runs through all the `@Autowiring` (that's working fine)
2. Spring runs through all the `@PostConstruct`s in *some* order

In yours, `One`'s @PostConstruct happens to run first, THEN `Two`'s afterwards.

Comment: In my experience spring doesn't do all the autowiring first... https://stackoverflow.com/a/64649202/32453

Answer (score 2):

If you want Bean `One` to initialize before `Two`, you can add [@DependsOn](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

```
@DependsOn({"One"})
@Service
public class Two {
```

> May be used on any class directly or indirectly annotated with Component or on methods annotated with Bean.

Although you will get null in the other log

Comment: It gets super funky with circular dependencies, sadly... https://stackoverflow.com/a/64649202/32453