# How can I use autowired in a non db access model

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a model for service to use. But the autowired annotation returns null value. However this autowire works well in service. Is there any to do in the Module class?

```
public class Module{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Function> functions;

    @Autowired
    private SysModuleLgDao sysModuleLgDao;



    public Module() {
        sysModuleLgDao.doSth();
    }
}
```

This is my repo class:

```
@Repository
public interface SysModuleLgDao extends JpaRepository<SysModuleLgEntity, Long> {
    public List<SysModuleLgEntity> findByModuleLgIdAndLanguageId(long moduleLgId,long languageId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Object's constructor is called before Spring has a chance to do the wiring, so `sysModuleLgDao` reference is in its default state (i.e. `null`). Spring's context loading happens in a later phase, long after the default constructor has been called.

You can work around the problem by performing `doSth` in a different lifecycle phase, after the Spring bean has been constructed. This can be achieved via [the `@PostContstruct` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations):

```
public class Module {
    @Autowired
    private SysModuleLgDao sysModuleLgDao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialise() {
        // at this point sysModuleLgDao is already wired by Spring
        sysModuleLgDao.doSth();
    }
}
```

More details here: [Why use @PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3406555/1240557)

Comment: The PostConstruct method seems not to be called in the object new. Is there any config in spring boot?

Comment: Yes, you need configuration and yours is apparently incorrect but you didn't show any so there's no way to tell what's wrong. Also, what's "object new"?

Comment: I would like to call constructor directly from my service like 

`@Service("MyService")`
`public class MyService(`
    `public void myMethod(){`
        `Module module = new Module();`
    `}`
`)`

Comment: In this case, your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19896870/1240557 (explanations in the accepted answer)