# How to initialze resources after JAX-WS initialization

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

How can I initialize my loggers and property readers after the `JAX-WS` initialization?

I tried this but did not work. Am I missing something?
My goal is to initialize everything that my webservice needs after deployment. Is this possible? Thanks

```
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Initialize some things");
    }

}
```

PS
I used the `@WebService` annotation approach in creating my WS.

Comment: you can use [interceptors](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html)

Comment: The JAX-WS spec supports the `@PostConstruct` annotation (like most other managed objects in the container). Using this, you can perform your initialization actions in an `@WebService`. see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct