# Constructor is not calling when clicking second time link PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, constructor, navigation

I wanted to call constructor when I click link second time. For first Time it's calling constructor.

Here is example,

I have few navigation links

- Link 1
- Link 2
- Link 3

When I click on Link 2, It call Link 2 constructor and then I click on Link 3 then its call Link 3 constructor, Now when I click back to Link 2 then Just page displayed but constructor of Link 2 is not calling.

How to call Link 2 constructor whenever I click on Link 2?

I am using PrimeFaces + Java

Comment: please add some of your code to see if there's any problem

Comment: `<p:menuitem value="TestOrder"  onclick="selectComponentLink(this)" url="/pages/Selection.xhtml"/>
<p:menuitem value="Run"  onclick="selectComponentLink(this)" url="/pages/Execution.xhtml"/> ` on clicking TestOrder Link, I wanted to call `public L2sTestOrderBean()
 {
  //BO initialise code 
 }`  but when i click 1st time it will call constructor but second time if i click then it won't call same constructor.

Comment: try to change `url` by `outcome` ?!?

Comment: Tried something like this `<p:menuitem value="TestOrder" onclick="selectComponentLink(this)" outcome="/pages/Selection.xhtml"/>` ' but result is same.

Answer (score 0):

You should @PostConstruct annotation instead of regular constructer to be sure that dependencies are injected and the (post construct) method wil be called only once in bean's life cycle.

[Why use @PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct)

There are bean species with different life cycles.

[How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

At your situation, you want a new bean for every page or request. So you could use ViewScoped or RequstScoped bean.

Example:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class L2sTestOrderBean {

@PostConstruct
public void init(){

//initialize

}

}
```