# components not available/unavailable dependecncies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

jdk 1.8

When I run my dynamic web project, I get the following problem.  I don't what is going on so please help me out with this.

Please explain to me what is `@PostConstruct` in Java class and why is is giving this error

```
WELD-001468: Method initialize defined on class com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ViewBookingDetails is not defined according to the specification. It is annotated with @javax.annotation.PostConstruct but it does not have a void return type.
at com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ViewBookingDetails.initialize
```

.

```
18:21:46,433 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWS0004: Stopping service jboss.ws.endpoint."RGExtranet.war"."com.revguru.crs.hsdbooking.webservice.service.HSDHotelResNotifService"
18:21:46,435 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWS0004: Stopping service jboss.ws.endpoint."RGExtranet.war"."com.revguru.crs.hsdbooking.webservice.service.HSDEviivoIntegration"
18:21:46,435 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = RGExtranet.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
18:21:46,527 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment RGExtranet.war (runtime-name: RGExtranet.war) in 100ms
18:21:46,528 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "RGExtranet.war" (runtime-name: "RGExtranet.war")
18:21:54,484 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGExtranet.war/WEB-INF/lib/c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
18:21:55,080 ERROR [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJSF0002: Could not load JSF managed bean class: com.revguru.crs.web.general.vo.AmenityContainer
18:21:55,523 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment RGExtranet.war
18:21:55,900 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
18:21:55,905 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.metadata] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS024061: Adding service endpoint metadata: id=com.revguru.crs.hsdbooking.webservice.service.HSDHotelResNotifService
 address=http://localhost:8080/RGExtranet/HSDHotelResNotifService
 implementor=com.revguru.crs.hsdbooking.webservice.service.HSDHotelResNotifService
 serviceName={http://service.webservice.hsdbooking.crs.revguru.com/}HSDHotelResNotifServiceService
 portName={http://service.webservice.hsdbooking.crs.revguru.com/}HSDHotelResNotifService
 annotationWsdlLocation=null
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=false
18:21:55,906 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.metadata] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS024061: Adding service endpoint metadata: id=com.revguru.crs.hsdbooking.webservice.service.HSDEviivoIntegration
 address=http://localhost:8080/RGExtranet/HSDEviivoIntegrationService
 implementor=com.revguru.crs.hsdbooking.webservice.service.HSDEviivoIntegration
 serviceName={www.eviivo.com/adapter}HSDEviivoIntegrationService
 portName={www.eviivo.com/adapter}HSDEviivoIntegration
 annotationWsdlLocation=WEB-INF/wsdl/HSDEviivoIntegrationService/HSDEviivoIntegrationService.wsdl
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=false
18:21:55,917 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-6) Creating Service {http://service.webservice.hsdbooking.crs.revguru.com/}HSDHotelResNotifServiceService from class com.revguru.crs.hsdbooking.webservice.service.HSDReservation
18:21:56,064 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-6) Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8080/RGExtranet/HSDHotelResNotifService
18:21:56,070 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS024074: WSDL published to: file:/D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/data/wsdl/RGExtranet.war/HSDHotelResNotifServiceService.wsdl
18:21:56,081 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-6) Creating Service {www.eviivo.com/adapter}HSDEviivoIntegrationService from WSDL: WEB-INF/wsdl/HSDEviivoIntegrationService/HSDEviivoIntegrationService.wsdl
18:21:56,113 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-6) Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8080/RGExtranet/HSDEviivoIntegrationService
18:21:56,164 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS024074: WSDL published to: file:/D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/data/wsdl/RGExtranet.war/HSDEviivoIntegrationService/HSDEviivoIntegrationService.wsdl
18:21:56,180 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = RGExtranet.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
18:21:56,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWS0003: Starting service jboss.ws.endpoint."RGExtranet.war"."com.revguru.crs.hsdbooking.webservice.service.HSDHotelResNotifService"
18:21:56,184 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWS0003: Starting service jboss.ws.endpoint."RGExtranet.war"."com.revguru.crs.hsdbooking.webservice.service.HSDEviivoIntegration"
18:21:56,213 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Event] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.CdiAnnotationProviderExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
18:21:58,076 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001468: Method initialize defined on class com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ViewBookingDetails is not defined according to the specification. It is annotated with @javax.annotation.PostConstruct but it does not have a void return type.
    at com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ViewBookingDetails.initialize(ViewBookingDetails.java:65)
  StackTrace
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.InterceptorMetadataUtils.isValidTargetClassLifecycleInterceptorMethod(InterceptorMetadataUtils.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.InterceptorMetadataUtils.isInterceptorMethod(InterceptorMetadataUtils.java:33)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.BeanMethods$4.processMethod(BeanMethods.java:348)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.BeanMethods.getMethods(BeanMethods.java:141)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.BeanMethods.getInterceptorMethods(BeanMethods.java:332)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.InterceptorMetadataUtils.buildMethodMap(InterceptorMetadataUtils.java:126)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.InterceptorMetadataReader.getTargetClassInterceptorMetadata(InterceptorMetadataReader.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InterceptionModelInitializer.initTargetClassInterceptors(InterceptionModelInitializer.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InterceptionModelInitializer.init(InterceptionModelInitializer.java:104)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.buildInterceptionModel(BeanInjectionTarget.java:94)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.initializeInterceptionModel(BeanInjectionTarget.java:89)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(BeanInjectionTarget.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetInitializationContext.initialize(InjectionTargetInitializationContext.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetService.initialize(InjectionTargetService.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:433)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

18:21:59,315 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001468: Method initialize defined on class com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ViewBookingDetails is not defined according to the specification. It is annotated with @javax.annotation.PostConstruct but it does not have a void return type.
    at com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ViewBookingDetails.initialize(ViewBookingDetails.java:65)
  StackTrace"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGExtranet.war\".WeldStartService"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
18:21:59,333 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "RGExtranet.war" with deployment "RGExtranet.war"
18:21:59,336 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectOneListboxTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectOneListboxTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectOneListboxTag".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectOneListboxTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SelectItemTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SelectItemTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SelectItemTag".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SelectItemTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.agents.container.AgentTermsContainer".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.agents.container.AgentTermsContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.agents.container.AgentTermsContainer".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.agents.container.AgentTermsContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.BookOutVO".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.BookOutVO".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.BookOutVO".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.BookOutVO".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.BookingConfirm".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.BookingConfirm".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.BookingConfirm".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.BookingConfirm".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ModifyBooking".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ModifyBooking".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ModifyOccupancyVO".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ModifyOccupancyVO".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ModifyOccupancyVO".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ModifyOccupancyVO".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.common.vo.CommonGlobalBean".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.common.vo.CommonGlobalBean".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.common.vo.CommonGlobalBean".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.common.vo.CommonGlobalBean".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.eviivo.vo.BookingHotelEviivo".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.eviivo.vo.BookingHotelEviivo".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.eviivo.vo.BookingHotelEviivo".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.eviivo.vo.BookingHotelEviivo".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.finance.vo.ManageAcceptedCreditCards".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.finance.vo.ManageAcceptedCreditCards".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.finance.vo.ManageAcceptedCreditCards".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.finance.vo.ManageAcceptedCreditCards".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.container.RulesPenaltyContainer".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.container.RulesPenaltyContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.container.RulesPenaltyContainer".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.container.RulesPenaltyContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.controller.GeotreeController".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.controller.GeotreeController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.controller.ManageEventsController".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.controller.ManageEventsController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.controller.ManageEventsController".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.controller.ManageEventsController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.controller.ManageMealPlanController".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.general.controller.ManageMealPlanController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HSDCommentsContainer".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HSDCommentsContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HSDCommentsContainer".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HSDCommentsContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HotelContainer".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HotelContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HotelHealthSafetyContainer".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HotelHealthSafetyContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HotelHealthSafetyContainer".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HotelHealthSafetyContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HotelMealPlanContainer".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HotelMealPlanContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HotelMealPlanContainer".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.container.HotelMealPlanContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelAmenitiesController".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelAmenitiesController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelAmenitiesController".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelAmenitiesController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelHealthSafetyController".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelHealthSafetyController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelHealthSafetyController".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelHealthSafetyController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelRatingController".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelRatingController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelRatingController".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelRatingController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelSupplementMealPlanController".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelSupplementMealPlanController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelSupplementMealPlanController".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelSupplementMealPlanController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelSupplementsController".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelSupplementsController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelSupplementsController".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.HotelSupplementsController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.vo.HotelAvailabilityUpdate".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.vo.HotelAvailabilityUpdate".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.vo.HotelAvailabilityUpdate".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.vo.HotelAvailabilityUpdate".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.vo.HotelQuickCloseOut".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.vo.HotelQuickCloseOut".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.vo.HotelQuickCloseOut".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.vo.HotelQuickCloseOut".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.reports.controller.ReportsController".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.reports.controller.ReportsController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.reports.controller.ReportsController".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.reports.controller.ReportsController".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.rm.vo.Seasonality".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.rm.vo.Seasonality".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.rm.vo.Seasonality".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."managed-bean.com.revguru.crs.web.rm.vo.Seasonality".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.RtfServlet".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.RtfServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.jsp.FormTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.jsp.FormTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.checkbox.HtmlCheckboxTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.checkbox.HtmlCheckboxTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.checkbox.HtmlCheckboxTag".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.checkbox.HtmlCheckboxTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.date.HtmlInputDateTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.date.HtmlInputDateTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.date.HtmlInputDateTag".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.date.HtmlInputDateTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.DocumentBodyTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.DocumentBodyTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.DocumentBodyTag".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.DocumentBodyTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.emailvalidator.ValidateEmailTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.emailvalidator.ValidateEmailTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.inputTextHelp.HtmlInputTextHelpTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.inputTextHelp.HtmlInputTextHelpTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.inputTextHelp.HtmlInputTextHelpTag".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.inputTextHelp.HtmlInputTextHelpTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.selectOneRow.SelectOneRowTag".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.selectOneRow.SelectOneRowTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.HtmlPanelTabTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.HtmlPanelTabTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.HtmlPanelTabTag".WeldInstantiator (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RGExtranet.war".component."org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.HtmlPanelTabTag".START]
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001468: Method initialize defined on class com.revguru.crs.web.booking.vo.ViewBookingDetails is not defined according to the specification. It is annotated with @javax.annotation.PostConstruct but it does not have a void return type.
> ```

You have a method named `initialize` in your class named `ViewBookingDetails`.  You annotated that method with `@PostConstruct`, *however* the return type of that method is not `void`.  Change the return type to `void` in order to use the method as a CDI PostConstruct method.

Here is some relevant documentation:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmgkd.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406631

Comment: thanks my problem is solved