# Multiple times construction

Tags: spring

How many times `Spring` is calling single `Singleton` constructor?

In which cases constructor can be called more than one time (for bean with the same id)?

EDIT:

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406631/4743869) is an answer that user is telling that can be more than once - I need more explanation for that.

Comment: It’s a singleton - what do you think the answer is?

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406631/4743869 is a little clue that can be and I want to know bigger explanation

Answer (score 0):

> How many times Spring is calling single Singleton constructor?

Only once; The default Bean Scope is **singleton**.

> In which cases constructor can be called more than one time (for bean with same id)?

Take a look at [Bean Scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)

> ## Scope Description
>
> #### singleton
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.
>
> #### prototype
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object instances.
>
> #### request
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP request; that is each and every HTTP request will have its own instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> #### session
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> #### global session
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a global HTTP Session. Typically only valid when used in a portlet context. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

What you need is scope **prototype**

[image: Spring Prototype Image]

So add a `@Scope("prototype")` to your bean definition like this:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype") //add this
public MyBean myBean()
{
    return new MyBean();
}
```

Comment: So you want to call `@PostConstruct` multiple times?

Comment: No, I want to know why constructor to same bean can be called multiple times.

Comment: Are you now talking about `@PostConstruct` or really just the default Java constructor? If you mean the later, well why not? You can instantiate (and therefore call the constructor of) any class you like as many times as you like.

Comment: I am not talking about calling constructor via `new`. I asked why `Spring` can call singleton's constructor (for bean with same id) more than once. I am not asking about PostConstruct.

Comment: So with constructor you mean the method annotated with `@Bean` returning a new instance of the bean? Spring won't call that more than once by default. At the start of the program it instantiates all beans, and only once.

Comment: I mean constructor of an object which is called when bean is created. Why in provided link which has +280 score is information that is possible?

Comment: The links _tells_ you @ByeBye. Passivation and proxying.