# How to pass injected bean to another injected object?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I would like to do the following

```
public class AClass {
   @Inject 
   private AnotherBean anotherBean;

   @Inject
   private AGenericClass agenericClass = new GenericClass(BClass.class,anotherBean);
}
```

Basically inject a bean and pass it to another bean that is also instantiated via Injection. Additionally pass another (non injected) argument to aGenericClass. The `AGenericClass` bean also has several `@Injected` beans. I know this is not possible the way I wrote it but is there a way to do it at runtime? I must say I am very new at dependency-injection via the cdi (and di in general).

Comment: Try to use PostConstruct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct

Comment: I added @PostConstruct. What I see though is that the injected beans in agenericClass dont get instantiated.